# Creating an SVG in JavaScript, won't display

Tags: javascript, svg

im having issues with generating an SVG within JavaScript, as the createElementNS is creating my circle like so:

```
<circle></circle>
```

The above prevents the circle from being rendered, it works find if I change it to the below:

```
<circle/>
```

This is how i'm creating my SVG

```
let svg = document.createElement("SVG");
let circleBackground = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

Which is generating the following:

```
<svg class="radialGenerator" width="400" height="400" viewbox="0 0 400 400" style="transform: rotate(-90deg);">
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="#e6e6e6"></circle>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fill="none" stroke-width="12" class="radialGenerator__value" stroke="#f77a52" style="stroke-dasharray: 885.929, 295.31;"></circle>
</svg>
```

** Edit **

The answer is that I was using createElement for the SVG, this also needs to be:

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

Comment: can you post link to duplicate?

Comment: Look at the top of the question, the link is there.

Comment: Hmm tbh then this isn't a duplicate question as if you read it i'm using `createElementNS` as the answer to the other question suggests... @RobertLongson

Comment: No you aren't: let svg = document.createElement("SVG");

Comment: And SVG is case sensitive so the element you want is svg, not SVG.